# Insert Discount - Coupon with SQL in NopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90

I do use nopCommerce 3.9 and I would like to insert coupon code from my C# program code. There are requirements such as 
"*Has shopping cart amount*" 
and "*Blocked on product*". 
The insert is working fine, I can see the inserted records and I think there are logically right. (The same process happening if I create Discount from Nop admin panel.)
When I open the inserted coupon from Nop admin the "Discount info" tab is perfect, on the "*Requirements*" tab I see the requirements
 "*Requirement Customer has x.xx amount in their shopping cart*" 
and the "*Requirement Block Discount on Product*", **but without value**. 
 If I modify the shopping cart value only (I don't modify the "blocked products" on purpose) and save it and reload the page, than everything is good. The blocked products are appeared too.
When I check the data tables I don't see any changes there. The records are the same as I inserted. 
I guess there is another table(s), where I have to update something, but I cannot find which one it is.

I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by *Has shopping cart amount* and *Blocked on product*

Comment: Thank you @Div for trying to help.
I mean when you create a Discount in NOP admin then you can add requirements.
With the "_Customer has x.xx amount in their shopping cart_ you can set up an amount, the customer has to spend this amount to make the discount works.
Example: The required amount is £70, the discount will not work if the customer has less than £70 in the shopping cart. The _Block Discount on Product_ means the discount is not working on these products.

Comment: Yes that is clear description, and what is the issue to add discount pragmatically?

Comment: The insert is working fine, I can see the inserted records and I think there are logically right. (The same process happening if I create Discount from Nop admin panel.)
When I open the inserted coupon from Nop admin the "**Discount info**" tab is perfect, on the "**Requirements**" tab I see the requirements
"_Requirement Customer has x.xx amount in their shopping cart_" 
and the "_Requirement Block Discount on Product_", but without value.

Comment: I inserted £70 with my program but the amount is 0. I inserted product ids in the "Block Discount on Product" fields, but the field is empty. 
If I modify the shopping cart value only, type 70 (I don't modify the "blocked products" on purpose) and save it and reload the page, than everything is good. The **blocked products are appeared too** even I didn't touch them.
When I check the data tables on SQL I don't see any changes there. The records are the same as I inserted. 
**I guess there is another table(s), where I have to update something, but I cannot find which one it is.**

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, I believe OP want to insert the new discount rule with two things:

1. Cart has minimum total X.
2. Cart has specific product(s) Y.

And the issue is,

> Its working properly if they apply discount rule from admin panel,
>   however, applying it programmatically couldn't store *specific
>   products* on a single call.

There are different tables for discount in nopCommerce.

`Discount` - main table 
`DiscountRequirement` - stores requirement information 
`Discount_AppliedToProducts` - stores discounted products information

Creating a discount rule first time will add entry in discount table only. Then the id of discount table will be used for reference to the `DiscountRequirement` and `Discount_AppliedToProducts` table.

Comment: Not exactly,
the discount is valid for all products, but I want to exclude some products, so I don't need to use `Discount_AppliedToProducts` table. If I create a Discount in nopCommerce with my criteria there is noting in the `Discount_AppliedToProducts` table. The exclusion list in the `Setting` table. I believe my inserts are okay, but an update or more update is missing on other tales(s). But which one, that is my question.

Comment: Then you have to do reverse in this case, add rest of the products in `Discount_AppliedToProducts` table except exclude discounted products

Comment: Yes that is sound logically, but we have this _Requirement Block Discount on Product_ plugin in `Discounts` which does the job so we don't need to reverse it.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're taking of *Requirement Block Discount on Product plugin*, anyway I'm now leaving for other continuity members...

Answer (score 1):

It was everything good with my process. The issue was the nopCommerce cache. The nopCommerce keeps the discounts in cache. After I clear the cache I can see my values.

Thanks for everyone who tried to help or had a thought!

Comment: ah, yes cache is evil many times with nop. Glad you found the issue :)